# why do echo work in %: foo.o rule but not in %: %.o?

Tags: makefile

This is my current makefile

```
.PHONY = all clean

all: foo
        @echo "Dependencies: $<"

%: %.o
        @echo "Checking.. $@, <- $<"
        gcc -lm foo.o -o foo
        @echo "\n"

%.o: %.c
        @echo "Creating object.. $@, <- $<"
        gcc -c foo.c
        @echo "\n"

clean:
        @echo "Cleaning up..."
        rm -rvf foo.o foo
```

When I run make, it doesn't print out any echoed strings, but I still get the executable file. This is all the things that get printed to the terminal

```
gcc                             foo.c   -o foo
echo "Dependencies: foo"
```

When I replace `%: %.0` rule with `%: foo.o`, everything is printed to the terminal normally

```
Creating object.. foo.o, <- foo.c
gcc -c foo.c


Checking.. foo, <- foo.o
gcc -lm foo.o -o foo


Dependencies: foo
rm foo.o
```

In both cases, I still get the executable file `foo` and it works normally, but why do I get 2 different results in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run make, it doesn't print out any echoed strings, but I still get the executable file.

Since you do not have an explicit rule for building `foo`, (GNU) `make` performs an [implicit rule search](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html#Implicit-Rule-Search), by which it attempts to find a chain of one or more pattern rules, whether user-provided or built-in, by which it can build `foo`.  Although it *could* choose to apply your rule to build `foo.o` from `foo.c` and then your rule to build `foo` from `foo.o`, it has a shorter chain available: a built-in rule for building `foo` directly from `foo.c`.  It chooses the latter because it's shorter.

> When I replace `%: %.0` rule with `%: foo.o`, everything is printed to the terminal normally

This is a bit of a quirk of the implicit rule search procedure.  When you make that change, `make` identifies the revised rule as "applicable" for building `foo` on account of the only prerequisite having an explicit name (this is item 5.3 in the algorithm described in the manual).  The built-in rule for building directly from `%.c` is also applicable, but the one given in the makefile has precedence (among rule chains of the same length).  The fact that `make` has to figure out separately how to make `foo.o` doesn't enter into consideration in this case (this is the quirky part, but follows clearly from the docs).

Of course, this particular quirk is rarely triggered, because a rule of the form of your revised one is almost always inappropriate.  It says that whatever target is to be built, it can be built from `foo.o`, via the provided recipe, but that recipe *really* works only for building `foo`.  Instead of `%: foo.o`, then, you really ought to make it `foo: foo.o`:

```
.PHONY = all clean

all: foo
        @echo "Dependencies: $<"

foo: foo.o
        @echo "Checking.. $@, <- $<"
        gcc -o $@ $< -lm
        @echo "\n"

%.o: %.c
        @echo "Creating object.. $@, <- $<"
        gcc -c foo.c
        @echo "\n"

clean:
        @echo "Cleaning up..."
        rm -rvf foo.o foo
```

Additional notes:

- link library options such as `-lm` should come at the end of the link line.  The relative order of these and object files on the command line matters.
- Avoid repeating yourself.  Rules' recipes should use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-variables_002c-automatic) where possible to avoid repeating the target or prerequisite names.

Comment: Thank you. I added `%: %.c` to cancel the built-in rule and it works as expected.